# How to open an Liblinear model (.llm) file that contains a SVM Model in python or C++

Tags: python, c++, svm, liblinear

I have a file with `llm` format which contains weights and bias of a trained SVM model. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything on the internet about how to open this file format. Does anyone here have any experience with this kind of files?

Comment: Please update your question with what you are trying to achieve, what you have done already. You can read on how to ask a question here: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Well I have a feature extractor written with pytorch which gives me the features of my image data set. now I want to classify them with a trained svm model. But the models were given to me in this format (*.llm). My problem is that I couldnt find a solution to open the model in python.